# Automapper : Set this to a property

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to do that with AutoMapper : Put the source object in a private property of the destination object.

Below the case I would like to do:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleApp12 {

    class B {
        public B() { }
    }

    class A {
        public B B { get; private set; }
        public A() { }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                 cfg.CreateMap<B, A>()
                    .ForMember(ma => ma.B, mb => mb) //Error mb can't be "this"
            );
            var mapper = new Mapper(config);

            var b = new B();
            var a = mapper.Map<A>(b);

            Debug.Assert(a.B != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to add B as a parameter of A constructor?

Comment: This is possible but in this case the constructor must be private or protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a slightly different syntax in the member mapping.

Note that the second argument is not the value you wish to map, but an expression via MapFrom of how to get to the value.

I've changed the lambda expression parameters to make it easier to read and also added a dummy property to prove it out.

```
void Main()
{
}



class B
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public B() { }
}

class A
{
    public B B { get; private set; }
    public A() { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<B, A>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
        });
        var mapper = new Mapper(config);

        var b = new B() { MyProperty = 123 };
        var a = mapper.Map<A>(b);

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        Debug.Assert(a.B != null);

        Debug.Assert(a.B.MyProperty == 123);

    }
}
``
```

Comment: I looked for far too complicated when it was that simple. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Topic glad to have helped, I too have been on a journey of enlightenment discovering the simple power of AutoMapper! :-)
I'm still learning!